# vagrant-scp : Providing a local path to a non-default drive to copy a file from my USB key to my vagrant VM

Tags: windows-10, vagrant

I'm trying this :

`vagrant scp D:\location vmname:\otherlocation`

But I get the following error :

```
The machine with the name 'D' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

I get that vagrant-scp interprets this `D:` as a VM name and not as my USB drive. From what I understood there are utilities that just can't handle drive names.

It at least looks like it's a known problem given the issues [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8239) and [here](https://github.com/invernizzi/vagrant-scp/issues/39).

I also tried to check the [`vagrant-scp` source code](https://github.com/invernizzi/vagrant-scp/blob/dbefe6bcdd082a3d8547260f3126ecb457006ece/lib/vagrant/scp/commands/scp.rb) but I'm not very fluent in ruby.

Is it possible to provide a local path from a non-default drive or make the command handle the drive name? If so, how?

**NB:** I successfuly achieved what I was trying to do by simply copying the file on my `C:` and thus avoiding having to provide a drive name, but I'm still curious about this issue.

---

The vagrant-scp usage as provided by the utility itself :

```
Usage: vagrant scp <local_path> [vm_name]:<remote_path>
       vagrant scp [vm_name]:<remote_path> <local_path>
Directories will be copied recursively.

Options:

        --[no-]color                 Enable or disable color output
        --machine-readable           Enable machine readable output
    -v, --version                    Display Vagrant version
        --debug                      Enable debug output
        --timestamp                  Enable timestamps on log output
        --debug-timestamp            Enable debug output with timestamps
        --no-tty                     Enable non-interactive output
    -h, --help                       Print this help
```